# Compiler error (regmap_config) => error: unknown field 'cache_type' specified in initializer

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am trying to build a I2C kernel driver but I am getting this error from the compiler: (related to struct regmap_config)

```
kernelDrv.h:64:2: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]

kernelDrv/kernelDrv.h:64:2: warning: (near initialization for 'kernelDrvRegmapConfig') [enabled by default]

kernelDrv/kernelDrv.h:65:2: error: unknown field 'cache_type' specified in initializer .cache_type = REGCACHE_RBTREE,
```

Thank you

Comment: So what is not clear in the warning message?

Comment: Seems the kernel headers used for compilation are too old, probably the whole kernel though. So, which kernel do you use?

Comment: It's probably to "thin" for an answer, so just commenting: look up the actual declaration of the `struct` in question in your kernel source. It seems to differ from what you expect.

Comment: The definition in question is here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/regmap.h?v=3.14#L210

Comment: Same question here: http://askubuntu.com/q/685552/419557

Comment: This kernel version 3.14.40